# Prevent git from zipping any files at certain condition

Tags: git, bash

I currently have a bash command setup in my jenkins which should help me add files to my git.

What I did is I'm checking the files that have changed since the previous commit, I then zip those files, unzip them in a directory and move them to my server through ssh. This works without a problem as long as I don't delete files through my commits.

When I delete a file it will try to add this file to the zip which then causes an error since the file isn't present anymore (obviously).

initially my command looked like this:

`git archive --output=publish/update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only $PREVIOUS $CURRENT)`

currently it looks like this:

`git archive --output=publish/update.zip HEAD $(git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only $PREVIOUS $CURRENT)`

what `--diff-filter=d` does is exclude any deleted files from the search.
HOWEVER when I do this and there are only files deleted in my commit the archive command will look like this:

`git archive --output=publish/update.zip HEAD`

So what happens is there are no files specified after the head causing the entire workspace to git zipped up and transfered to the server.
obviously this isn't what I want.

Does anyone have any idea how I could possibly fix this?

My entire bash command looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/FVuYr4LR)

Comment: Why are you sending files (that you are committing?) manually instead of just using git push/pull of the respective commits?

Comment: because I don't want to touch anything server side. This is a solution I can apply on as many sites and servers as I want. I have people with shared hosting and vps and what not so I felt that this would be the best way to go

Answer (score 0):

Use git relative refs and zip command directly.

The whole script could be something like:

```
# Create remove.sh so it removes at least one file - itself
printf "rm %q\n" remove.sh $(git diff --diff-filter=D --name-only HEAD~1) > remove.sh
# Create update.zip so it contains at least one file - remove.sh
zip update.zip remove.sh $(git diff --diff-filter=d --name-only HEAD~1)
```